# Give and take a battle?

Tags: commentaries, creation, ramchal, evil-inclination

http://www.aish.com/jl/p/wayofg-d/17-Created-for-Pleasure.html?mobile=yes

According to my own understanding the Ramchal thought that because HaShem is completely, perfectly, totally, absolutly, entirely etc. in His essence, He couldn't have created for His own; for selfish or self-supporting goals, else it would imply that He would 'miss' something and in that case He would't be complete, perfect, total etc.. So He did not create for Himself, but for another..

Doing something for another is esentially 'giving', and in order to give He made a receiver (a taker)

In order to really receive man had to have free will...

What I would like to know if this is the idea/reason of why we have a Yetzer HaRah, and it's self-centered (egocentric), because we are made to receive and take?

And how I should understand the Yetzer HaTov (altruistic selflessness) in comparison; how can we beget this part if we are made to receive and need to become selflessness and just follow His Will (Ein of milvado)?